# negative margin not working in jQuery .css({

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
  $('#thankYouMessage').css({"height": textHeight, "margin-top:": "-52px", "padding-left": "19px"});
```

`padding-left:` will execute but nothing with a negative margin? (`margin-top:` is ignored)

Comment: is the `margin-top` getting overwritten after that line is executed?

Comment: It just completely ignored, doesn't even show up in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#thankYouMessage').css({"height": textHeight, "margin-top": "-52px", "padding-left": "19px"});
```

you had a extra colon next to margin-top

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `"margin-top:"` should be `"margin-top"` (without the ':')

Comment: dam what timing of our answers